# Moving an image in html on click of a button using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just want to create make an image move from the left to the right of the page on click of a button.
I am using the below piece of code but it is not working. I am a novice in JQuery.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/
        jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
        $( "#but2" ).click(function() {
          $( "#vehi1" ).animate({ right:300px }, 500 );
        })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="homel11">
            <button id="but2"style="top:200px;left:30px;position:fixed">click me</button>
        </div>
        <div id="vehi" ><img id="vehi1" style="left:0px;position:relative;
        top:540px;"src="vehi.png" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there are thousands of duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind event in [document-ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#but2").click(function () {
        $("#vehi1").animate({
            right: 300px
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: binding is not helping in moving the image

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Effect demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>
      .toggler { width: 500px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
      #but2 { padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
      #effect { width: 240px; height: 135px; padding: 0.4em; position: relative; }
      #effect h3 { margin: 0; padding: 0.4em; text-align: center; }
      .ui-effects-transfer { border: 2px dotted gray; }

      .img-class{left:0px;position:relative;top:540px;}
      .btn-class-SO{top:200px;left:30px;position:fixed}
    </style>

    <script>
      $(function() {          
        $( "#but2" ).click(function() {
          $( "#vehi" ).effect("slide", 500);// run the effect
          //Here you can change the name of the effect you want
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <button id="but2"class="btn-class-SO">click me</button>
      <div id="vehi" ><img id="vehi1" class="img-class" src="vehi.png" />
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the image is not sliding

Comment: Try with document ready                                                                 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {         
        $( "#but2" ).click(function() {
          $( "#vehi" ).effect("slide", 500);// run the effect
          //Here you can change the name of the effect you want
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not having the DOM ready function declaration in the `script` tag. Include this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // your code..it is correct!
}
```

This is required in order to run jQuery code. Without this, jQuery code won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you have missed out document ready, also I have tidied up your code slightly, so it may make more sense to you:

http://jsfiddle.net/PH3ff/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button[data-move]").click(function() {
        $('img.to-move').animate({left: '200px'}, 500);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="to-move" />
<button data-move>click me</button>
```

CSS

```
.to-move {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:30px;
}
```

Comment: even after adding the document ready handler the code is not executing

Comment: Have a look at that example, remember to include your jQuery library in the page and also check the console for any errors. This may be helpful to you: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console